# jacoco jenkins plugin expects the classes and src code on Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, jacoco

Does Jenkins Plugin Jacoco expects the Actual classes, src code on Jenkins Server itself? or looks into Slave machine. for .exec file it found in slave machine but does not finds the classes in slave, it appears that it chcecking jenkins or am I missing

I see below Exception(/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log) during Jenkins build for Jacoco report.

```
While reading class directory: /home/JenkinsHome/jobs/Jacoco/builds/27/jacoco/classes
java.lang.IllegalStateException: basedir /home/JenkinsHome/jobs/Jacoco/builds/27/jacoco/classes does not exist
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner.scan(DirectoryScanner.java:308)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFileAndDirectoryNames(FileUtils.java:1942)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFileNames(FileUtils.java:1869)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFileNames(FileUtils.java:1851)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFiles(FileUtils.java:1825)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFiles(FileUtils.java:1808)
        at hudson.plugins.jacoco.ExecutionFileLoader.analyzeStructure(ExecutionFileLoader.java:125)
        at hudson.plugins.jacoco.ExecutionFileLoader.loadBundleCoverage(ExecutionFileLoader.java:137)
        at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportDir.parse(JacocoReportDir.java:102)
        at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoBuildAction.getResult(JacocoBuildAction.java:222)
        at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoPublisher.perform(JacocoPublisher.java:484)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1760)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the path to the class files. If this path does not exists "**/jacoco/classes" is the default value.

[image]